# Center input in a dynamic generated table

Tags: javascript, php, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

Im building an web-application where I have some problems about centering the input.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NemNs.png) is a picture of how the web-application looks like.

And this is the code (JS).

```
var x = document.getElementById("ddKamers").value;

var table = document.getElementById("table");
var row = table.insertRow();
var cell1 = row.insertCell();
var cell2 = row.insertCell();
var cell3 = row.insertCell();
var cell4 = row.insertCell();
var cell5 = row.insertCell();
var cell6 = row.insertCell();
var cell7 = row.insertCell();

cell1.innerHTML = x;
cell2.innerHTML = "<div class='col-md-6'><input name='stopcontacten[]' class='form-control' type='text'/></div>";
cell3.innerHTML = "<div class='col-md-6'><input name='lichtkringen[]' class='form-control' type='text'/></div>";
cell4.innerHTML = "<div class='col-md-6 center-block'><input name='schakelaars[]' class='form-control' type='text'/></div>";
cell5.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' id='cbTV' name='cbTV[]' class='form-control center-block'/>";
cell6.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' id='cbInternet' name='cbInternet[]' class='form-control center-block'/>";
cell7.innerHTML = "<button id='buttonDelete' type='button' class='btn btn-default' onclick='deleteRow(this)'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></button>";

kamerArray.push(x);
document.getElementById('kamers').value = kamerArray;
```

If anyone knows how to center the input, you'll help me a lot! 
For some reason I don't find anything on google.

Comment: You could use the very deprecated HTML `<center>` tag:`<center>I am centered!</center>`.

Comment: CSS - set the width, use `margin: auto;` ... what has this got to do with PHP or Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

you can center a div and its content this way

```
<div style = "margin:auto 0px;">
</div>
```

and for a table it would be like this

```
<td align="center">Text</td>
```

and with javascrip you can do it this way

```
cell1.style.textAlign = 'center';
```

and with bootstrap3 you can use text-center class for div

```
<div class="text-center">
    </div>

<td class="text-center">
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

To center text content within a table cell using javascript, you must do this:

```
cell1.style.textAlign = 'center';
```

Of course, if the content is within a div, then you may need to set the text align propery on the div as well depending on your stylesheet rules.

Bootstrap also contains a utility class called `text-center` that will center content within the element that you apply that class too.

One more thing, table cells have `align` attributes that you could also set.